# err : Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, composer-php

hello I have one problem

Composer JSON
https://pastebin.com/qfi10DAX

I have this error :

```
 Problem 1
    - Installation request for symfony/http-kernel dev-master -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[dev-master].
    - symfony/http-kernel dev-master requires symfony/error-catcher ^4.4|^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/error-catcher[4.4.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - symfony/web-server-bundle dev-master requires symfony/http-kernel ^4.4|^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[4.4.x-dev, 5.0.x-dev].
    - symfony/web-server-bundle dev-master requires symfony/http-kernel ^4.4|^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[4.4.x-dev, 5.0.x-dev].
    - symfony/http-kernel 5.0.x-dev requires symfony/error-catcher ^4.4|^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/error-catcher[4.4.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - symfony/http-kernel 4.4.x-dev requires symfony/error-catcher ^4.4|^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/error-catcher[4.4.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - symfony/http-kernel 4.4.x-dev requires symfony/error-catcher ^4.4|^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/error-catcher[4.4.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for symfony/web-server-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by symfony/web-server-bundle[dev-master].
```

what can I do to solve this?

My **composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "psr/container": "^1.0@dev",
        "symfony/event-dispatcher": "dev-master",
        "symfony/lock": "^4.3",
        "psr/log": "^1.1",
        "psr/event-dispatcher": "^1.0",
        "symfony/http-kernel": "dev-master",
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^4.3",
        "symfony/config": "^4.4@dev",
        "symfony/console": "dev-master",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "dev-master",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^4.3",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^4.3",
        "symfony/process": "dev-master",
        "symfony/yaml": "^3.4",
        "symfony/finder": "^4.3",
        "symfony/expression-language": "^4.3",
        "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "^4.3",
        "symfony/asset": "^4.3",
        "symfony/cache": "^4.3",
        "symfony/class-loader": "^3.4",
        "symfony/workflow": "^4.3",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/var-exporter": "^4.3",
        "symfony/validator": "^4.3",
        "symfony/translation": "^4.3",
        "symfony/templating": "^4.3",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "^4.3",
        "symfony/serializer": "^4.3",
        "symfony/security": "^4.3",
        "symfony/property-info": "^4.3",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/cache": "^1.8",
        "symfony/contracts": "^1.1",
        "symfony/debug": "^4.3",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "^4.3",
        "symfony/dotenv": "^4.3",
        "symfony/filesystem": "^4.3",
        "symfony/form": "^4.3",
        "symfony/security-guard": "^4.3",
        "symfony/http-client": "^4.3",
        "symfony/http-foundation": "dev-master",
        "symfony/inflector": "^4.3",
        "symfony/intl": "^4.3",
        "ext-ldap": "^7.3",
        "symfony/ldap": "^4.3",
        "symfony/mailer": "^4.3",
        "symfony/messenger": "^4.3",
        "enqueue/messenger-adapter": "^0.2.2",
        "enqueue/async-event-dispatcher": "^0.9.7",
        "enqueue/async-command": "^0.9.6",
        "symfony/web-link": "^4.3",
        "enqueue/sqs": "^0.9.11",
        "aws/aws-php-sns-message-validator": "^1.5",
        "enqueue/dbal": "^0.9.9",
        "enqueue/redis": "^0.9.7",
        "enqueue/fs": "^0.9.8",
        "enqueue/stomp": "^0.9.10",
        "php-http/stopwatch-plugin": "^1.2",
        "php-http/cache-plugin": "^1.6",
        "php-http/logger-plugin": "^1.1",
        "slim/slim": "^3.12",
        "zendframework/zend-diactoros": "^2.1",
        "ircmaxell/random-lib": "^1.2",
        "moontoast/math": "^1.1",
        "symfony/mime": "dev-master",
        "symfony/options-resolver": "^4.3",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^4.3",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.11",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "^1.11",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "^1.11",
        "symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme": "^1.11",
        "symfony/polyfill-intl-icu": "^1.11",
        "symfony/polyfill-intl-idn": "^1.11",
        "symfony/polyfill-intl-messageformatter": "^1.11",
        "symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer": "^1.11",
        "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "^1.11",
        "symfony/polyfill-php54": "^1.11",
        "symfony/polyfill-php55": "^1.11",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "^1.11",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "^1.11",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "^1.11",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "^1.11",
        "symfony/polyfill-php73": "^1.11",
        "symfony/polyfill-util": "^1.11",
        "symfony/property-access": "^4.3",
        "symfony/routing": "^4.3",
        "sylius/resource-bundle": "^1.5@dev",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "^4.3",
        "symfony/security-acl": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "^1.3",
        "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.4",
        "alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter": "^1.1",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.3",
        "symfony/psr-http-message-bridge": "^1.2",
        "nyholm/psr7": "^1.1",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "^4.3",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "^3.5",
        "jmikola/geojson": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "^1.2",
        "sylius/locale": "^1.5",
        "solarium/solarium": "^5.0",
        "minimalcode/search": "^1.0",
        "propel/propel": "^2.0@dev",
        "monolog/monolog": "^2.0@dev",
        "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "dev-master",
        "sentry/sentry": "^2.0@dev",
        "php-amqplib/php-amqplib": "^2.8@dev",
        "php-console/php-console": "dev-master",
        "graylog2/gelf-php": "^1.4@dev",
        "ruflin/elastica": "^6.0@dev",
        "ocramius/package-versions": "^1.4",
        "doctrine/coding-standard": "^6.0",
        "composer/composer": "^1.9@dev",
        "infection/infection": "dev-master",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.2@dev",
        "phpunit/php-invoker": "^2.0@dev",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/couchdb": "^1.0@dev",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.0@dev",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^6.2@dev",
        "true/punycode": "dev-master",
        "jakub-onderka/php-parallel-lint": "dev-master",
        "jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter": "dev-master",
        "predis/predis": "^2.0@dev",
        "sylius/money-bundle": "^1.6@dev",
        "akeneo/phpspec-skip-example-extension": "^4.0@dev",
        "phpspec/nyan-formatters": "^1.0@dev",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5@dev",
        "lakion/api-test-case": "^5.0@dev",
        "symfony/doctrine-bridge": "^4.3@dev",
        "lchrusciel/api-test-case": "^5.0@dev",
        "polishsymfonycommunity/symfony-mocker-container": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "jean85/pretty-package-versions": "^1.0@dev"
    },
    "conflict": {
       "symfony/doctrine-bridge": "4.2.0",
       "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.3.0"
   }
}
```

Comment: You could have just edited your question.. x)

Comment: Do it yourself.

Comment: @DylanKas its my composer.json https://pastebin.com/ybYAV2yU

Answer (score 1):

Why have you ended with `dev-master` in `composer.json`?

You can fix it in 2 ways:

- **the right way** - replace all unstable requirements in your `composer.json` file to stable ones (like `^4.3` for `symfony/http-kernel`)
- **the wrong way** - allowing Composer to install non-stable dependencies with [`minimum-stability`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) flag, by adding this to `composer.json`:

  ```
  {
      "minimum-stability": "dev"
  }
  ```